# Как вывести бадж рядом с названием элемента в цикле NgFor по условию?

Tags: angular

Вобщем запутался в простых вещах... Есть два массива:
1) persons с объектами типа

```
{
name: "Brown",
personId: "dsfrauAUHjfrkf32"
}
```

2) badges

```
{
personId: "dsfrauAUHjfrkf32",
badge: true
}
```

У меня в компоненте методом NgFor выводится список людей. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при выводе этого списка рядос с именем отображался бадж, если совпадают id и badge = true

То есть сложность для меня в том, что список имен в компоненте формируется из одного массива, а информация по баджам хранится в другом.

Сделано так потому, что эти массивы формируются по subscription из разных коллекций базы данных. И сейчас переписывать логику БД нет времени и желания

Comment: в чем проблема пройтись в цикле по массивам и объединить их?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать метод в контроллере который будет работать как то так

```
personHasBadge(personId: string): boolean {
  return this.badges.find((badge) => badge.personId === personId);
}
```

вызывать в ngIf

либо как написал @overthesanity подготовить данные перед ngFor
и закинуть сначала данные есть badge или нет в каждый объект из persons

Comment: в данном случае сложность рендеринга увеличивается в разы, что заставит Angular не просто через директиву `ngFor` рендерить список, но еще и создать `persons.length` инстансов директив `ngIf`, где предикатом будет результат функции `personHasBadge`, в итоге мы получаем `O(n ^ 2 + n)` сложность, это затратно, вес одного инстанса `NgIf` класса 120 байт, также у этой директивы есть `ngOnChanges` хук, который на каждый механизм обнаружения изменения делает проверку на то, не изменился ли предикат

Comment: да, я сейчас пробую подготовить данные правильно

Comment: сначала скомбинировал две подписки и дождался загрузки, потом в отдельном методе составил новый массив через for и уже из него отрисовал список сотрудников  - ура))